# Remove past observations up to nearest observation to given date by group

Tags: r

Although I have achieved what I want (see result below), I find my approach kind of convoluted. I would like to remove all observations till the nearest observation *before* a cut-off date (here `cut-off`), by group. I cannot simply calculate the nearest observation using `min(abs(x - date))` because there can be ties of observations that are equally distant in the positive and negative (e.g., group "b" in `mydf`).

I solved it by looking for the index of the last observation where `date - cut_off <=0`, and then using this index in `dplyr::slice()`. I am very curious about other approaches though.

Very very open for non-dplyr solutions.

**Every group contains at least one row where `observation date - cutoff date <= 0`**

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(8)

mydf <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:3], each = 5), date1 = as.Date(sample(15), origin = '1970-01-01'), cut_off = as.Date(rep(sample(10, 3), each = 5), origin = '1970-01-01'))

mydf %>% arrange(group, date1) %>% group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(diff = date1 - cut_off, 
         min_abs = min(abs(date1 - cut_off)))

#> # A tibble: 15 x 5
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>    group date1      cut_off    diff    min_abs
#>    <fct> <date>     <date>     <drtn>  <drtn> 
#>  1 a     1970-01-03 1970-01-05 -2 days 0 days 
#>  2 a     1970-01-05 1970-01-05  0 days 0 days 
#>  3 a     1970-01-08 1970-01-05  3 days 0 days 
#>  4 a     1970-01-13 1970-01-05  8 days 0 days 
#>  5 a     1970-01-15 1970-01-05 10 days 0 days 
#>  6 b     1970-01-02 1970-01-09 -7 days 2 days 
#>  7 b     1970-01-06 1970-01-09 -3 days 2 days 
#>  8 b     1970-01-07 1970-01-09 -2 days 2 days 
#>  9 b     1970-01-11 1970-01-09  2 days 2 days 
#> 10 b     1970-01-12 1970-01-09  3 days 2 days 
#> 11 c     1970-01-04 1970-01-11 -7 days 1 days 
#> 12 c     1970-01-09 1970-01-11 -2 days 1 days 
#> 13 c     1970-01-10 1970-01-11 -1 days 1 days 
#> 14 c     1970-01-14 1970-01-11  3 days 1 days 
#> 15 c     1970-01-16 1970-01-11  5 days 1 days

# min(abs(x)) does not help when the distance from neg and pos values is tied, see group b
```

**Desired result (solution already pretty ok)**

```r
mydf %>% 
  arrange(group, date1) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(diff = date1 - cut_off) %>% 
  slice(max(which(diff <= 0)):n()) 
# finds index of last element in "diff" which fullfills condition 

#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>    group date1      cut_off    diff   
#>    <fct> <date>     <date>     <drtn> 
#>  1 a     1970-01-05 1970-01-05  0 days
#>  2 a     1970-01-08 1970-01-05  3 days
#>  3 a     1970-01-13 1970-01-05  8 days
#>  4 a     1970-01-15 1970-01-05 10 days
#>  5 b     1970-01-07 1970-01-09 -2 days
#>  6 b     1970-01-11 1970-01-09  2 days
#>  7 b     1970-01-12 1970-01-09  3 days
#>  8 c     1970-01-10 1970-01-11 -1 days
#>  9 c     1970-01-14 1970-01-11  3 days
#> 10 c     1970-01-16 1970-01-11  5 days
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are couple of approaches with `dplyr` :

We can use `top_n` to select top n dates from each group where `n` is calculated for each group differently based on number of values which are greater than `cut_off`.

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% group_by(group) %>% top_n(sum(date1 > cut_off) + 1, date1) 

#   group date1      cut_off   
#   <fct> <date>     <date>    
# 1 a     1970-01-05 1970-01-05
# 2 a     1970-01-08 1970-01-05
# 3 a     1970-01-13 1970-01-05
# 4 a     1970-01-15 1970-01-05
# 5 b     1970-01-11 1970-01-09
# 6 b     1970-01-12 1970-01-09
# 7 b     1970-01-07 1970-01-09
# 8 c     1970-01-14 1970-01-11
# 9 c     1970-01-16 1970-01-11
#10 c     1970-01-10 1970-01-11
```

Although this selects the rows correctly but note that `top_n` does not sort the data so you might want to add `arrange(group, date1)` at the end of the chain.

---

Another approach is similar to the one posted in OP using `slice`

```
mydf %>% 
  arrange(group, date1) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  slice((which.max(date1 > cut_off) - 1):n())

#  group date1      cut_off   
#  <fct> <date>     <date>    
# 1 a     1970-01-05 1970-01-05
# 2 a     1970-01-08 1970-01-05
# 3 a     1970-01-13 1970-01-05
# 4 a     1970-01-15 1970-01-05
# 5 b     1970-01-07 1970-01-09
# 6 b     1970-01-11 1970-01-09
# 7 b     1970-01-12 1970-01-09
# 8 c     1970-01-10 1970-01-11
# 9 c     1970-01-14 1970-01-11
#10 c     1970-01-16 1970-01-11
```

We can also tweak this to use in `filter`.

```
mydf %>% 
  arrange(group, date1) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(row_number() >= which.max(date1 > cut_off) - 1)
```

which can be translated in base R as :

```
new_df <- mydf[with(mydf, order(group, date1)), ]
subset(new_df, ave(date1 > cut_off, group, FUN = function(x) 
                seq_along(x) >= (which.max(x) - 1)))
```

Comment: I have so far always struggled to understand `top_n` Would the `top_n` solution possibly be the only herein (the entire thread) presented solution which would not depend on the order of the data frame?

Comment: @Tjebo Yes, `top_n` does not require ordering of rows. It automatically selects the rows with top values.

Answer (score 2):

You could detect the rows where the dates are above your threshold, then use lead on them to keep one more value :

```r
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
  arrange(group,date1) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(lead(date1 > cut_off, default = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    group date1      cut_off   
#>    <fct> <date>     <date>    
#>  1 a     1970-01-05 1970-01-05
#>  2 a     1970-01-08 1970-01-05
#>  3 a     1970-01-13 1970-01-05
#>  4 a     1970-01-15 1970-01-05
#>  5 b     1970-01-07 1970-01-09
#>  6 b     1970-01-11 1970-01-09
#>  7 b     1970-01-12 1970-01-09
#>  8 c     1970-01-10 1970-01-11
#>  9 c     1970-01-14 1970-01-11
#> 10 c     1970-01-16 1970-01-11
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to remove all observations up to the nearest observation
>   to a given date, by group. I cannot simply calculate the nearest
>   observation using min(abs(x - date)) because there can be ties of
>   observations that are equally distant in the positive and negative
>   (e.g., group "b" in mydf).

Your criteria is tied, you need to deliberately choose a way to break ties - you could choose to pick whichever entry comes first: (or last, check ?top_n)

```
mydf %>% 
  mutate(diff =  abs(date1- cut_off)) %>% 
  arrange(group, diff) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  top_n(n = 1, wt = -diff )

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   group [3]
  group date1      cut_off    diff  
  <fct> <date>     <date>     <drtn>
1 a     1970-01-12 1970-01-11 1 days
2 b     1970-01-07 1970-01-02 5 days
3 c     1970-01-03 1970-01-04 1 days
```

*for some reason I got different values even while using your seed (8)

If you need to filter only cases where diff <= 0, just add that to the pipe chain.

Comment: true, I wasn't thinking of breaking ties deliberately! good move.

Answer (score 1):

The sorting and diff is a wise move. So for the last part, since your dates are already sorted, for each group, you use which.min to call out the row that is nearest, and keep rows that are >= this value:

```
mydf %>% 
arrange(group, date1) %>% 
group_by(group) %>%
mutate(delta = abs(date1- cut_off)) %>%
filter(1:n() >= max(which(delta == max(delta[delta<=0]))))

# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   group [3]
   group date1      cut_off    delta  
   <fct> <date>     <date>     <drtn> 
 1 a     1970-01-05 1970-01-05  0 days
 2 a     1970-01-08 1970-01-05  3 days
 3 a     1970-01-13 1970-01-05  8 days
 4 a     1970-01-15 1970-01-05 10 days
 5 b     1970-01-07 1970-01-09  2 days
 6 b     1970-01-11 1970-01-09  2 days
 7 b     1970-01-12 1970-01-09  3 days
 8 c     1970-01-10 1970-01-11  1 days
 9 c     1970-01-14 1970-01-11  3 days
10 c     1970-01-16 1970-01-11  5 days
```

Comment: ok i re-read your question. so yes, i missed the <= 0 part.. So my code only works for this example.. Lemme try again

Comment: I am not sure if this is actually only working in this example... I am pondering over your statement within `filter` and not sure why this works... Pretty mind twisting

Comment: Hmm I think the trick is to get out for each group_by what is row with the maximum of your <= 0 difference. And from there, the n() will give you nrow, you give a boolean to filter() and it will work

Comment: I have edited my answer, a bit more complicated and I hope it's correct... there might be a shorter way to write max(which(delta == max(delta[delta<=0]))

Comment: Heya, I just reviewed the code and noticed it's actually not working. Sorry that I missed it when I asked it, but I had then found a different way. Now it's become relevant again.